# Matplotlib savefig method saves empty image

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm following an example from a textbook covering Matplotlib. The following code saves a graph when run through command-line Python, but when ran through Jupyter it saves an empty image. Why is that happening?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '-')
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), '--')
fig.savefig('image.png')
```

Comment: I don't think so - it doesn't involve explicitly creating a Figure object like I did.

Comment: Based on your code, I also don't think this a duplicate question. However, I will not vote to reopen it because the problem is not reproducible with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running the same code in Jupyter but without your first line:

```
#%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '-')
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), '--')
fig.savefig(r'C:\Users\new_folder\image.png')
```

Make sure you specify a correct path for the output image. This way is working for me just fine and I get the .png image

Comment: It didn't change anything for me, the saved image is still blank.

Comment: Maybe try more matplotlib build-in commands, as `%matplotlib` or `%matplotlib qt`, instead of `%matplotlib inline`. You can list the available matplotlib backends with `%matplotlib --list` and try some

Comment: Check some documentation here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html